# Trying to trigger event after order is placed

Tags: event-observer

I am using Magento 1.9.1

Here is my config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VivasIndustries_Smartparser>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VivasIndustries_Smartparser>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <smartparser>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Model</class>
            </smartparser>
        </models>
        <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <vivasindustries_smartparser_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>clearcartitems</method>
                </vivasindustries_smartparser_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>       
        <helpers>
            <smartparser>
                <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Helper</class>
            </smartparser>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
             <smartparser>
                 <class>VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Block</class>
             </smartparser>                         
         </blocks>      
     </global>   
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <vivasparser>
                                            <title>vivasparser - All</title>
                                        </vivasparser>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
          <layout>
            <updates>
              <smartparser>
                <file>smartparser.xml</file>
              </smartparser>
            </updates>
          </layout>
    </adminhtml>     
</config>
```

Here is my obsrerver:

```
<?php

class VivasIndustries_Smartparser__Model_Observer
{
   public function checkPound() {




    Mage::log("$NowTime has started autmated pound currency check rate of $PoundRate status check!", null, "PoundCurrency.log", true);  

    }

    public function clearcartitems($observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::log("Order is placed",  null, "Order.log", true);
        Mage::log($data->debug(),  null, "Order.log", true);
    }   
}
```

However when i place an order there nothing happens. The log is not created.
Where is my mistake and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your class name

```
class VivasIndustries_Smartparser__Model_Observer
```

With

```
class VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Model_Observer
```

Answer (score 1):

Your observer class name looks different than one in XML file, try to remove one not needed underscore. This is class name:

```
VivasIndustries_Smartparser__Model_Observer
```

And this is used in XML file:

```
VivasIndustries_Smartparser_Model_Observer
```